# 1 out of 3 Buttons not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout

so I have an layout that includes:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="Go"
    style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="See All"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonOk"
    style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonAll"
    style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What I want is all 3 buttons going across the bottom but only ButtonBack and ButtonAll are showing up but not taking up the whole bottom. Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Tyler

Comment: How is the ButtonAll aligned? To the left with no margin?
Maybe yo also must say that ButtonOk must be placed to left? That shouldn't be needed because you have given the buttons same weight but you never know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Your edited Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonOK"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Go" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonAll"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="See All" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonBack"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Go"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="See All"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonOK" 
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Back"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonAll"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Set the lay out orientation based on your choice. Use  `android:orientation="vertical"` or

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two overdrawn buttons. There's `ButtonOK` and then a rule with non-existing target `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonOk"` (notice the lowercase `k` in `Ok`). This makes the "All" button to draw over the "Ok" button.

To make them appear side-to-side, change the ids to match each other.

To make the buttons be of equal size and take up all horizontal space, change the `RelativeLayout` to a `LinearLayout` and change the button widths to `0px`, removing the `layout_toRightOf` rules that are only valid in a `RelativeLayout`.

(Note that `layout_weight` only works in a `LinearLayout`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="See All"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonOk"
   style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay" />
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonBack"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="Back"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonAll"
    style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ButtonOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonBack"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Go"
        style="@style/btnStyleBreakerBay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If there wasn't a typo in the identifiers, this would cause a circular dependency exception.